# How can I add a TextView below a MapView?

Tags: android, layout, android-mapview, android-linearlayout

I followed [Hello Views, Google Map View](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) and now I want to add a `TextView` under below the `MapView`. I have only changed the layout file `main.xml` and placed the `MapView` and the `TextView` in a vertical `LinearLayout`. My Eclipse is set to build this automatically, but when I run the application in the emulator, I can only see the `MapView`.

How can I add a `TextView` below a `MapView`?

Here is my layout `main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="my key"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My TextView"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you have is that you are using `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` in your `MapView`.

I don't get if you want:

- The `TextView` to be over the map
- Shrink the `MapView` to leave space for the `TextView`

In the first case use a `<RelativeLayout>` instead of a `<LinearLayout>` and play with the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for the `TextView`.

In the second case, use `android:layout_weight`. I don't have eclipse opened but placing `android:layout_weight="1"`to the `TextView` should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, I added a weight on both the `MapView` (1.0) and on the `TextView` (0.0) and now it works.

Answer (score 5):

You might like to try a RelativeLayout like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MyTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:apiKey="Your api key"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/MyTextView"" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I couldn't get MapViews to work very well with LinearLayouts

Answer (score 2):

**Only** the combination of

`<TextView android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" ... />`

**and**

`<com.google.android.maps.MapView android:layout_above="@+id/MyTextView" ... />`

worked for me.