# Android : maps from intent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

In my application : I have Find Home Tab..
On clicking it and after passing the co-ordinates from emulator control it should show the map...

If I use intent

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=42.35892,-71.05781&daddr=40.756054,-73.986951");
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Its not showing the tabs of my application...

How do I associate intent with my application and make it show the map in my application..

Also is it possible to show textbox below the map displayed by this intent??

Please help..

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for doing that! Unfortunately, I don't have an answer for you, but there are lots of other smart people here. I'm counting on them!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to include the map in your Activity.

Here the infos by google:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Text below the Map:
[How can I add a TextView below a MapView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143858/how-can-i-add-a-textview-below-a-mapview)

You can then set the tab to display the MapActivity you created the way explained int hose links above.

To draw the path in the Map do the same as the person here: [android get duration from maps.google.com directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951007/android-get-duration-from-maps-google-com-directions)

Comment: thanks.. but in that case I have to draw the route myself on mapview overlay...  I want to use the intent and show the map displayed by intent on top of my application so that the buttons of my application and visible to user.. is this possible ??

Comment: i just tried it to put the browser or the google map app into a tab. is not working :( i can put my own activity in a tab, but not theirs. they just start the new app. seems you will have to display the path by yourself.

Comment: just found another post about showing the driving directions in the  own map.. added the link to my answer.

Comment: thanks patrick... I am already showing the path, but I wanted detailed directions to be shown to the user... adding map using intent works best but I wanted the controls in my application to be shown as well.. looks like its not possible :(